# Where to save "read" flag for user's article - CoreData or User Defaults?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I have an app where users first view a list of `Articles`, which shows the unread number, and can then read the articles. Once the user reads an `Article`, its object's `read` flag is set to `TRUE`.

What's the best practice for saving the "read" flag (used for UI) on these articles? The immediate benefit I see for User Defaults is that the data will be backed up to iCloud, so all the articles will persist their correct status over time, restores, etc.

There may be some bigger and better benefits to using CoreData though, which I'm not very familiar with.

What do you recommend for this case?

Comment: Remember you can keep Core Data info in iCloud as well.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` isn't *synced* with iCloud, only backed up. Your Core Data store is, by default, also backed up but not synced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have stored this in Core Data, why? The benefits of filtering (querying) read from unread articles and if your app have a login (or might get in the future) you can associate this information for each user profile. You will also have all this information in one place giving you the benefit of simpler code.

Comment: And if you put article-specific attributes in `NSUserDefaults` (or really any storage other than Core Data), you'll have to do a lot of work to keep them in sync as articles get deleted, etc.